# Как проверить переменные, которые возвращает контроллер?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
def index
  @user
end
```

Как проверить значение переменной user, когда в тестах перейдем в метод контроллера index?

Comment: До или после выполнения метода?

Comment: Если есть экземпляр класса контроллера, то можно использовать его метод `instance_variable_get`, то есть так: `instance_of_controller.instance_variable_get(:@user)`, после того, как отработает метод `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно переменные контроллера проверяются с помощью метода рспека - `assigns`, так, например, для вашего случая:

```
get :index
expect(assigns(:user)).to_not be_nil
```

На сайте [RelishApp](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs) можно почитать подробнее.